# RandomForestClassifier should be a binary classifier

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, tf.keras

I have written a code that performs rogue device detection using Random Forest and Decision Tree classifiers. The models were successfully trained. However, it returns an error at inference:   "raise ValueError(classification_error) ValueError: RandomForestClassifier should be a binary classifier." I want to evaluate the classifiers' performance by drawing the ROC and DET curves using scikit-learn libraries "plot_roc_curve" and "plot_det_curve." The same error is produced even with other classifiers, like XGBoot, SVM, and Naive Bayes. I have converted the target values to binary (0s and 1s), but the same error is generated. Below is a snippet of my code:

```
# Load RFF extractor.
feature_extractor = load_model(feature_extractor_name, compile=False)

LoadDatasetObj = LoadDataset()

# Load enrollment dataset.
data_enrol, label_enrol = LoadDatasetObj.load_iq_samples(file_path_enrol, 
                                                         dev_range_enrol, 
                                                         pkt_range_enrol)

ChannelIndSpectrogramObj = ChannelIndSpectrogram()

# Convert IQ samples to channel independent spectrograms.
data_enrol = ChannelIndSpectrogramObj.channel_ind_spectrogram(data_enrol)

# Extract RFFs from cahnnel independent spectrograms.
feature_enrol = feature_extractor.predict(data_enrol)
del data_enrol

# Load the test dataset of legitimate devices.
data_legitimate, label_legitimate = LoadDatasetObj.load_iq_samples(file_path_legitimate, 
                                                                   dev_range_legitimate, 
                                                                   pkt_range_legitimate)
# Load the test dataset of rogue devices.
data_rogue, label_rogue = LoadDatasetObj.load_iq_samples(file_path_rogue, 
                                                         dev_range_rogue, 
                                                         pkt_range_rogue)

# Combine the above two datasets into one dataset containing both rogue
# and legitimate devices.
data_test = np.concatenate([data_legitimate,data_rogue])
label_test = np.concatenate([label_legitimate,label_rogue])

from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
# Create an instance of LabelEncoder
#label_encoder = LabelEncoder()

# Convert IQ samples to channel independent spectrograms.
data_test = ChannelIndSpectrogramObj.channel_ind_spectrogram(data_test)

# Extract RFFs from channel independent spectrograms.
feature_test = feature_extractor.predict(data_test)
del data_test

classifiers = {
                "Random Forest": RandomForestClassifier(),
                "Decision Tree": DecisionTreeClassifier()
                }

# Label the packets sent from legitimate devices as 1. The rest are sent by rogue devices
# and are labeled as 0.
true_label = np.zeros([len(label_test),1])
true_label[(label_test <= dev_range_legitimate[-1]) & (label_test >= dev_range_legitimate[0])] = 1

# Encode the string labels into integer values
#true_label = label_encoder.fit_transform(true_label)

print('\nfeature_test',feature_test.shape)
print('\ntrue_label',np.ravel(true_label.astype(int)))

# prepare plots

fig, [ax_roc, ax_det] = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(11, 5))

for name, clf in classifiers.items():
    clf.fit(feature_enrol, np.ravel(label_enrol))

    plot_roc_curve(clf, feature_test, np.ravel(true_label.astype(int)), ax=ax_roc, name=name)
    plot_det_curve(clf, feature_test, np.ravel(true_label.astype(int)), ax=ax_det, name=name)

ax_roc.set_title('Receiver Operating Characteristic (ROC) curves')
ax_det.set_title('Detection Error Tradeoff (DET) curves')

ax_roc.grid(linestyle='--')
ax_det.grid(linestyle='--')

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

The following is the error:

```
  plot_roc_curve
  X, estimator, response_method, pos_label=pos_label)
  File "C:\Users\fhabmo\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow-21\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\_plot\base.py", line 101, in _get_response
    raise ValueError(classification_error)
ValueError: RandomForestClassifier should be a binary classifier
```